# water molecular structure

Tags: water, hydrogen, molecules

If someone claim that chemical formulation for the water isn't $H_2O$, how we can prove for he/she that water has constituted of $H_2O$ molecules. Generally based on what evidences we sure that water is $H_2O$ (has one oxygen and two hydrogens per each molecule) and isn't anything else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Electrolyze the water and collect the electrolysis products in separate containers.  When this is done, it is immediately seen that one container has twice as much gas in it as the other container.  If the containers are at the same temperature and pressure, this means that there are twice as many moles of one electrolysis product as there are of the other electrolysis product.

Now, try to ignite the gas in the container that contains the smaller volume.  Note that while that gas does not burn, it VIGOROUSLY supports combustion.  Also note that the gas in that container has no odor, and is not noxious to breathe.  Try to light the gas in the other container, and note that in its pure form, that gas burns in a controlled fashion.

Take some of the gas from the "larger volume" container, and put it in a balloon.  Note that the balloon floats in air, indicating that the gas in the balloon is somewhat less dense than air.  Now, note from the periodic table of the elements that the only gas in that table which burns and is also lighter than air is hydrogen.  Also note that the only gas in the periodic table which is breathable and vigorously supports combustion is oxygen.